# Images don't show in Components in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, vue-component

I'm learning how to use VueJS and managed to do a simple page showing the menu of a restaurant (in a single file).

Now I'm using vue-cli and refactored what I did : everything is working except images.

My structure is like this :

```
/node_modules
/public
/src
    /assets
        /picture.jpg
        /[...]
    /components
        /MenuItem.vue
    App.vue
    main.ts
```

In src/App.vue :

```
<template>
[...]
         <ul>
            <MenuItem
              v-for="plat in plats"
              :name="plat.name"
              :price="plat.price"
              :url="plat.url"
              :role="role"
              :plat="plat"
              :supprimer="supprimer"
              :key="plat.name"
            />
         </ul>
[...]
</template>

<script>
import MenuItem from './components/MenuItem'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    MenuItem
  },
  data() {
    return{
      plats: [
        {name: "Steak de boeuf", price: 5.99, url: "/assets/steak.jpg"},
        {name: "Coq au vin", price: 8.99, url: "/assets/coq.jpg"},
        {name: "Gencives de porc", price: 12.99, url: "/assets/porc.jpg"},
        {name: "Entrée", price: 4.99, url: "/assets/entrée.jpg"},
        {name: "Plat du jour", price: 14.99, url: "/assets/plat.jpg"}],
[...]
</script>
```

In src/components/MenuItem.vue :

```
<template>
    <li class="plat">
        <img :src="url"/><p> {{ name }} - {{ price }}€</p>
        <p v-if="role=='admin'" @click="supprimer(plat)"> Supprimer le plat </p>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MenuItem',
  props: ['name','price','url','role','plat','supprimer']
}
</script>
```

I thought this might be because of the path of pictures but I tried absolute/relatives paths and nothing worked.
I tried to change the path to "./assets/...", "./src/assets/...", etc, because I'm not sure from which place vuejs is searching for the pictures.

When I run the code everything shows correctly, except that the images are replaced by the "not found image" symbol :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocsgI.jpg)

Comment: I think the documentation should help you https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules

Comment: I read this doc and I understood that "/assets/picture.jpg" should work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where you are keeping your images. In your case use [`require`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#asset-url-handling) with `src` path `(@)`:

```
plats: [
    {
      name: "Steak de boeuf",
      price: 5.99,
      url: require('@/assets/steak.jpg')
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't understand that I had to use require + @, this is now working !

Answer (score 0):

As said by Albert in the comment, you have at least two ways to load images: removing the slash (e.g., `assets/foo.jpg`) or, better, link them by just adding a `@` before the relative path like: `@/assets/foo.jpg`; in short, `~` loads the `/node_modules/` relative path, for example if you want to link Bootstrap, while `@` stands for `/src/`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because expression inside v-bind are executed in runtime, webpack aliases work in compile time.

Try wrapping your url in `require` like this:

```js
{name: "Steak de boeuf", price: 5.99, url: require("assets/steak.jpg")}
```